# How can access to gitlab through docker

Tags: docker, gitlab

I'm trying to run gitlab through docker container on my web server.
I can reach my server with 192.168.80.xxx address.

here is what've done

- Get gitlab image from docker

  `docker pull gitlab/gitlab-ce`
- Then run

  ```
  docker run --detach \
  --hostname 192.168.80.xxx \
  --publish 443:443 --publish 8081:80 --publish 2289:22 \
  --name gitlab \
  --restart always \
  --volume /srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab \
  --volume /srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab \
  --volume /srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab \
  gitlab/gitlab-ce
  ```

Like port 80(apache) & 22 are already used, I've changed them into 8080 and 2289

- Now I go into my browser and check 192.168.80.xxx:8081 but nothing seems to work.

I was wondering "ok and what if i try to reach my container through its IP adress ?"

So I get back its address with the following line :

```
docker inspect 4170434ef181
```

And I try it `http://192.17.0.2:8081`, nothing too...

So guys, how can I use this container? how can I access it?

For informations my Document root path is defined like `DocumentRoot "/var/apache/www"` in my httpd.conf file

Cheers

Comment: You should connect to `<server-ip>:8080`

Comment: it doesn't works.

Answer (score 0):

`--hostname 192.168.80.xxx` -> usually, you define a string, not an ip adress. And this hostname is (per default) only valid inside your docker network.

If you are publishing ports `443` and `8080`, you should be able to access your server at `192.168.80.xxx:8080` or `192.168.80.xxx:443` - except there are some additional firewalls?!

Is your container running (`docker ps`)?

Comment: of course my docker container is running `4170434ef181        gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest    "/assets/wrapper"        22 hours ago        Up 22 hours (healthy)      0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2289->22/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8081->80/tcp   gitlab`

Comment: And I'm almost sure that is my apache server is causing the issue